# how to change content type in email header

Tags: php, phpmailer

How to set the content-type:application/pdf in phpmailer ? I don't want to set any other content-type like text/plain or mutlipart.

Is there any why we can do that ?

Comment: The developer of PHPMailer states: "PHPMailer doesn't allow building arbitrary MIME structures, but it has a whole bunch of presets covering common scenarios".

Comment: Sending an email that's pretending to be a PDF is not going to work. Email readers can't read PDF files as emails, it's like trying to drive a train up a river. It simply doesn't work like that.

Comment: In theory there is no restriction on doing this - email doesn't care what format you send – but in practice you can only realistically use formats that clients support. If PHPMailer did allow arbitrary MIME structures, the "right" way to do this would be to provide a `multipart/alternative` that contained a PDF document and a plain-text fallback for clients that couldn't display the PDF. I suspect that doing this would be a largely useless academic exercise though!

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this with PHPMailer, and it doesn't require a custom MIME structure, but I strongly recommend that you don't, for the reasons others have said – it's likely to break in most email clients. A plain-text message with a PDF attachment is much more likely to work. If you insist on trying this, do it like this:

```
$mail->ContentType = 'application/pdf';
$mail->Encoding = PHPMailer::ENCODING_BASE64;
$mail->Body = file_get_contents('file.pdf');
```

Don't try to use `AltBody` or add any other attachments; they won't work well.

Comment: Thanks.. let me try this

Comment: I'm getting error for 
$mail->Encoding = PHPMailer::ENCODING_BASE64;
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'ENCODING_BASE64'

Comment: @pramodmodankapu If `\PHPMailer\PHPMailer::ENCODING_BASE64;` is missing, you probably have an ultra outdated version of it

Comment: Hi @DanielW. I used file_get_contents but.. It was not sending any mail.. So tried addAttachment.. It worked but it shows me multipart in header

Comment: That's what adding attachments with `addAttachment` does. When you say "it was not sending any mail", describe exactly how, show your revised code and debug output in your question.